# Remove small blobs from image

Tags: c++, opencv

I need to remove all blobs at image, but cannot do it.
I tried many thresholding operations, but nothing helps.
I'm using OpenCV and Qt (C++).
Example:

```
cv::adaptiveThreshold(input, output, 125,
      ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, THRESH_BINARY_INV, 13, 25);
```

Input/Output:

[image: Input Image]

[image: Output Image]

Comment: It is quite possible that your time developing any sort of a solution is more expensive than the cost of third-party APIs that solve that problem and charge per-captcha. Have you considered that option? Also, why did you assume that thresholding will somehow remove blobs? That's not what it does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you're like hacking something :)

I suggest you try with some Blob Detection algorithm... give a look to [this link](https://www.learnopencv.com/blob-detection-using-opencv-python-c/). Then you can filter blobs by area for example.

Here a short snippet:

```cpp
using namespace cv;
// Read image
Mat im = imread( "blob.jpg", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE );

// Set up the detector with default parameters.
SimpleBlobDetector detector;

// Detect blobs.
std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;
detector.detect( im, keypoints);

// Draw detected blobs as red circles.
// DrawMatchesFlags::DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS flag ensures the size of the circle corresponds to the size of blob
Mat im_with_keypoints;
drawKeypoints( im, keypoints, im_with_keypoints, Scalar(0,0,255), DrawMatchesFlags::DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS );

// Show blobs
imshow("keypoints", im_with_keypoints );
waitKey(0);
```

This is the result:
[image]

All the blobs are highlighted with a circle

Also [morphological operations](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html) can improve the image. In particular, an opening and closing operation can improve the image and remove noise:

This after opening:

[image: Opening]

This after a closing operation:

[image]

Comment: This kinda reads more like a comment than an answer, but it does link to the solution (although dropping links in place of code in answers is frowned upon here).

Comment: @RTbecard I've modified the reply so it doesn't depend on the links anymore. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Great!  I've come across more than few questions where the only relevant answer for me buried critical info in dead links.  Thanks for taking the time to update an old answer!